# Facebook Prophet - `k initialized to invalid value (-nan)` in logistic growth

Tags: python, facebook

When I'm using  prophet with `growth == 'logistic'` I get the following error
`k initialized to invalid value (-nan)`
After a little debug I found the issue. 
The issue raises in case  the `y` of the minimum date  is half of the `y` max, and the `df['cap_scaled'] == 1`.

the following line assigns `2` into `r0`

```
r0 = max(1.01, df['cap_scaled'].ix[i0] / df['y_scaled'].ix[i0])
```

and this line assigns `0` into `L0`

```
L0 = np.log(r0 - 1)
```

this line assigns `0` into m

```
m = L0 * T / (L0 - L1)
```

and this line divides by zero

`k = L0 / m`

How  should I fix this? 
The workaround I thought about is to subtract or add epsilon to the `y` in the min date. Is it a good one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was fixed and I think it'll be released in the next version. 
For now the workaround should be like this [commit](https://github.com/facebookincubator/prophet/commit/306053656343f0fc7b55ee45909c72ec5d84738d).